# How add missing sequence in a list based on month and year?

Tags: c#, linq, entity

Let's suppose we have those values from a database :

- Month: 5, Total: 100, Year: 2019, Id: 1
- Month: 7, Total: 45, Year: 2019, Id: 1
- Month: 5, Total: 55, Year: 2019, Id: 2
- Month: 9, Total: 110, Year: 2019, Id: 2

Then I have to generate rows for Months 6 and 8 that are missing from the list with Total : 0 for Id: 1 and Id: 2

The final result should be:

- Month: 5, Total: 100, Year: 2019, Id: 1
- **Month: 6, Total: 0, Year: 2019, Id: 1**
- Month: 7, Total: 45, Year: 2019, Id: 1
- Month: 5, Total: 55, Year: 2019, Id: 2
- **Month: 6, Total: 0, Year: 2019, Id: 2**
- **Month: 7, Total: 0, Year: 2019, Id: 2**
- **Month: 8, Total: 0, Year: 2019, Id: 2**
- Month: 9, Total: 110, Year: 2019, Id: 2

How can I do that with LINQ and C#?
It's even harder if I think about the end of the year, e. g: Month 12, Year: 2019 and Month 2, Year: 2020.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to group the records by (id and year) and find the boundary (first month and last month) in each group to fill the blanks:

```
    db.NAME_OF_THE_TABLE
        .ToArray() // materialize the query, since this group by is unlikely to be supported by linq2...
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.Year }, (k, g) =>
        {
            var months = new { First = g.Min(x => x.Month), Last = g.Max(x => x.Month) };

            // left join to fill the blank between the records
            return (
                from month in Enumerable.Range(months.First, months.Last - months.First + 1)
                join row in g on month equals row.Month into match
                from x in match.DefaultIfEmpty(new TYPE_OF_RECORD { Id = k.Id, Year = k.Year, Month = month, Total = 0 })
                select x
            );
        })
        .SelectMany(g => g) // flatten the grouping
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an extension method to compute the number of months between two months:

```
public static class DateTimeExt {
    public static int MonthDiff(this DateTime d1, DateTime d2) => (d1.Year-d2.Year)*12+d1.Month-d2.Month;
}
```

You can create a range of months and then fill in the missing months. I use a `Dictionary` to lookup whether a month already exists:

```
var ans = db.GroupBy(r => r.ID)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .SelectMany(rg => {
                var rgd = rg.ToDictionary(r => (r.Month, r.Year));
                var First = rg.Min(r => new DateTime(r.Year, r.Month, 1));
                var Last = rg.Max(r => new DateTime(r.Year, r.Month, 1));
                return Enumerable.Range(0, Last.MonthDiff(First) + 1).Select(moffset => {
                    var wd = First.AddMonths(moffset);
                    return rgd.TryGetValue((wd.Month, wd.Year), out var r) ? r : new { ID = rg.Key, wd.Month, wd.Year, Total = 0 };
                });
            });
```

The `AsEnumerable` should pull the query information local so the rest runs in LINQ to Objects.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the generate the missing Data and Create an Union. For example,

```
var list = new []
{
    new Data{Month=5,Total=100,Year=2019,Id=1},
    new Data{Month=7,Total=100,Year=2019,Id=1},
    new Data{Month=5,Total=100,Year=2019,Id=2},
    new Data{Month=9,Total=100,Year=2019,Id=2},
    new Data{Month=2,Total=100,Year=2020,Id=2}
};

var result = list.GroupBy(x=>x.Id)
                    .Select(x=>
                    {
                        var minDate = x.ToList().Select(c=> new DateTime(c.Year,c.Month,1)).Min();
                        var maxDate = x.ToList().Select(c=> new DateTime(c.Year,c.Month,1)).Max();

                        return x.ToList().Union(Enumerable.Range(0, Int32.MaxValue)
                                         .Select(e => minDate.AddMonths(e))
                                         .TakeWhile(e => e <= maxDate)
                                         .Select(e => new Data{Month=e.Month, Total=0,Year=e.Year,Id=x.Key}))
                                         .OrderBy(v=> new DateTime(v.Year,v.Month,1))
                                         .GroupBy(c=>new {c.Month,c.Year})
                                         .Select(g=>g.First());
                    }).SelectMany(v=>v);
```

Where Data is defined as

```
public class Data
{
    public int Month{get;set;}
    public int Year{get;set;}
    public int Total{get;set;}
    public int Id{get;set;}
}
```